# Horizontal ProgressBar in Honeycomb ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-3.0-honeycomb

On my api level 13 tablet I'm using the holo light theme for the Activity and it works pretty well.
The only problem is that I need to show an indeterminate progress when an AsyncTask has fired and I'd like to have an indeterminate bar immediately under the ActionBar (like Chrome).
In my Activity onCreate:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);    
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
setProgressBarVisibility(false);
```

My Activity theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <style name="RunTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    ???
    ???
    ???
  </style>

</resources>
```

whatever I write in 'MyActionBar' style the progressbar insists to be a **spinner** in the ActionBar and NOT a bar under it.
Thanks in advance
L

Comment: have you been able to do it?

Comment: not exactly an answer, but this could help: https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh